# Обертка вокруг bash силами С++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, многопоточность

Идея заключается в следующем: Есть программа на С++ (можно еще python использовать, но хочется с осями поиграться) программа запускает два потока, в одном потоке bash консоль внутри нее запускается программа = В, это В работает на подобии консоли, т.е. в нее могут поступать некие команды и она в зависимости от них выдает результат, главное условие что бы это В не прекращала своей работы, пока она не выполнит нудные действия (порядок этих действий заранее не известен так же как их количество). Вторая дочерняя программа по идее обрабатывать данные которые ей пришли из вне (например с клавиатуры) и посылать их программе В,и работать с этим результатом. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через что реализовать? `Exec` работает не так он ждет пока завершиться процесс и в него нельзя походу дела посылать данные. Пайпы вроде как тоже ждут пока завершиться процесс (вот про них надо чуть больше кстати почитать) и еще главная проблема как один поток должен управлять другим.

Comment: Интересная идея. А в чём вопрос?

Comment: Не, пайпы не ждут. Через них обычно и делают.

Comment: Да? Спасибо, пойду грызть учебники.

Comment: Подождите, сейчас придёт @avp, он гуру в таких штуках.`

Comment: Да? Спасибо, тогда буду их изучать. А взаимодействие через них можно реализовать ?

Comment: Спрашиваете! Ещё как.

Comment: Я не знаю что происходит, но при обновлении страницы сайт странно отображает коментарии и я вроде отправил первый, но обновил страницу и он мне его не показал, тогда я написал второй "Да?.....", Добавте кто нибудь это как ответ отмечу вопрос решеным

Comment: @nrot Здесь не пишут технические задания.

Comment: Если полностью управлять (эмулируя пользователя за терминалом), то наверное лучше всего forkpty.
Вечером посмотрю повнимательней и попробую какой-нибудь примерчик нарисовать. Пайпы тоже можно, но там больше ограничений на протокол взаимодействия и требований к fflush

Comment: Коллеги, закрывать не надо (там уже 4 тревоги). Вопрос, конечно, сформулирован "не очень", но в принципе понятен (а главное,  многие вообще не представляют такую технику программирования).

Comment: Четко разделите все потоки, процессы и командную оболочку в изощренной схеме межпроцессного взаимодействия, которую вы предлагаете. Я не могу сходу понять как она работает. На вскидку согласен с @avp и @Vlad `forkpty и mkfifo`

Comment: И еще не известно что вы хотите получить в итоге за счет столь сложной схемы? Что конкретно она должна обеспечивать, какую задачу решать? Может на самом деле вам подойдет какой-то вариант взаимодействия процессов по проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала стоит почитать `man forkpty` (со всеми SEE ALSO), а потом можно обсудить вопрос более конкретно.

Надеюсь, пример (пытался сделать как можно короче, почти никаких проверок) пояснит как можно обмениваться (в дуплексе) данными с дочерними процессами. Для этих процессов организуется терминал за которым вместо человека выступает написанная им программа (в данном случае main).

```
// avp 2015 link with -lutil for using forkpty()

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>

FILE *
run_bc (char *cmd)
{
  int master;
  pid_t child = forkpty(&master, 0, 0, 0);

  if (!child) {
    char *bc[] = {
#ifdef USE_BASH
      "/bin/bash",
      "-c",
#endif
      "/usr/bin/bc",
      0
    };
    if (cmd)
      bc[
#ifdef USE_BASH
     2
#else
     0
#endif
     ] = cmd;
    execvp(bc[0], bc);
    err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "exec %s", bc[0]);
    // NOT REACHABLE
  }

  if (master >= 0) {
    // сделаем pty RAW (отключим echo (а заодно сигналы и EOF (вот это грустно)))
    struct termios t;
    tcgetattr(master, &t);
    cfmakeraw(&t);
    tcsetattr(master, TCSAFLUSH, &t);

    return fdopen(master, "r+");
  }

  return 0;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  FILE *pty = run_bc(av[1]);
  if (!pty)
    err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "run_bc");

  char str[LINE_MAX];

#if USE_POLL
  struct pollfd fds[2];
  fds[0].fd = 0;
  fds[0].events = POLLIN;
  int pfd = fileno(pty);
  fds[1].fd = pfd;
  fds[1].events = POLLIN;

  fcntl (pfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(pfd,F_GETFL)|O_NONBLOCK);
  // это нужно, чтобы не подвисать при построчном чтении (по лени) pty
  // учтите, PTY станет неблокируемым и в уже запущенных в run_bc() процессах

  for (;;) { // я оставил немного отладочной печати для понимания ситуации
    int n = poll(fds, 2, -1);

    if (n < 0)
      err(EX_OSERR, "poll");
    if (fds[0].revents) {
      if (fds[0].revents & (POLLHUP | POLLERR)) {
        puts("stdin hup or err");
        break;
      }
      if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
        if (!fgets(str, LINE_MAX, stdin)) {
          puts("EOF");
          break;
        }
        fputs(str, pty);
      }
    }

    if (fds[1].revents) {
      if (fds[1].revents & (POLLHUP | POLLERR)) {
        puts("pty hup or err");
        break;
      }
      if (fds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
        errno = 0;
        while (fgets(str, LINE_MAX, pty)) 
          fputs(str, stdout);
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
          puts("pty EOF");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }


#else

  // очень простой вариант - 2 независимых процесса 
  // работает только для команд, ориентированных на посторчный ввод-вывод
  pid_t p; 
  if (p = fork()) {
    // parent читает stdin и пересылает его в pty
    while (fgets(str, LINE_MAX, stdin))
      fputs(str, pty);
    fputs("\04", pty); // пошлем EOF
    // Тут один тонкий момент.
    // Не все (как bc) сами обнаруживают EOF, 
    // а мы (по лени) сделали RAW PTY, 
    // поэтому драйвер не будет генерить настоящий EOF
    // Убъем на всякий случай child --> pty точно закроется
    // и для процессов под ним возникнет EOF
    kill(p, 9); 
  } else {
    // child читает вывод команды
    while(fgets(str, LINE_MAX, pty))
      fputs(str, stdout);
    // похожая ситуация возникает, когда bc завершается по команде quit,
    // а parent висит на fgets(stdin) --> убъем его перед exit
    puts("Fin");
    kill(getppid(), 9);
    exit(0);
  }

#endif

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Теперь его можно оттранслировать, например

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc 2proc.c  -lutil
```

получим вариант с 2-мя процессами в main и непосредственным запуском `bc` и запустим, завершая ^D

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
2 + 2
4
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Еще один вариант, остановим вводом `quit`

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc 2proc.c -DUSE_POLL -lutil
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
2 * 22
44
quit
pty hup or err
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

А теперь так (думаю, возможность поработать с шеллом Вас порадует)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc 2proc.c -DUSE_POLL -DUSE_BASH -lutil
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 'sh -i'
$ cd /tmp
$ ls -a
.   config-err-hqooMP  .esd-115   .X0-lock   .xfsm-ICE-8HB63X
..  .esd-1000          .ICE-unix  .X11-unix
$ vi ttt
$ cat ttt

12345
qwerty

$ EOF
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

На самом деле vi работает не слишком красиво, поскольку tty (stdin, а не pty) в каноническом режиме. Если его тоже перевести в raw в начале программы, то vi будет выглядеть как положено (но возникнут другие проблемы).

Впрочем, это уже другие вопросы (по управлению терминалом).

Аналогично (на основе poll) можно реализовать взаимодействие более 2-х процессов (остается только написать в main-процессе коммутатор :)), например, GUI на wish с  каким-то вычислителем и  базой данных ...

Comment: Просто шаманство, взаимодействие процессов в *nix реально далеко не так просто как кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: @igumnov, понятно, что я здесь просто напрочь забил на все wait-ы, сигналы с масками и т.д.

Comment: Все равно это качественный пример. Я еще понял наконец где можно наблюдать примерно такую же схему. Команда внешней фильтрации в Vim. Можно запустить его, написать в первую строчку буфера `echo "2+2"| bc`. Затем набрать `:.!sh` и в результате в буфер на место команды действительно вернется `4`. Мы и правда тогда получим процесс который запустил шелл в котором еще один процесс что-то получил извне что-то с этим делает и возвращает обратно и при этом оригинальный Vim работает нормально в это время с другими буферами.

Comment: Нереально круто, кстати.

Comment: Это очень круто. Простите, что забросил вопрос на целый год и еще за те банальные ошибки, которые были в вопросе. Жаль я не помню, что за проект у меня был. Спасибо всем за советы и ответы